# Почему не распечатывается 64-х битное число?

Tags: c++, c

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t x8 = 0xFF;
    uint16_t x16;
    uint32_t x32, x24;
    uint64_t x64, x56, x48, x40;

    x16 = x8 <<8;
    x24 = x8 <<16;
    x32 = x8 <<24;
    x40 = x8 <<32;
    x48 = x8 <<40;
    x56 = x8 <<48;
    x64 = x8 <<56;

    printf("\n");
    printf("x8 = 0x%016x\n", x8);
    printf("x16 = 0x%016x\n", x16);
    printf("x24 = 0x%016x\n", x24);
    printf("x32 = 0x%016x\n", x32);
    printf("x40 = 0x%016x\n", x40);
    printf("x48 = 0x%016x\n", x48);
    printf("x56 = 0x%016x\n", x56);
    printf("x64 = 0x%016x\n", x64);

    return 0;
}
```

Вот, что распечатывается:

```
x8 = 0x00000000000000ff
x16 = 0x000000000000ff00
x24 = 0x0000000000ff0000
x32 = 0x00000000ff000000
x40 = 0x0000000000000000
x48 = 0x0000000000000000
x56 = 0x0000000000000000
x64 = 0x0000000000000000
```

Почему значения больше 32-х бит не распечатываются, несмотря на то, что переменные являются 64-х битными?

EDITED:

Спасибо @Mark Shevchenko и @Владимир Мартьянов !!!
Рабочий код таков:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t x8 = 0xFF;
    uint16_t x16;
    uint32_t x32, x24;
    uint64_t x64, x56, x48, x40;

    x16 = x8 <<8;
    x24 = x8 <<16;
    x32 = x8 <<24;
    x40 = (uint64_t)x8 <<32;
    x48 = (uint64_t)x8 <<40;
    x56 = (uint64_t)x8 <<48;
    x64 = (uint64_t)x8 <<56;

    printf("\n");
    printf("x8 = 0x%016llX\n", x8);
    printf("x16 = 0x%016llX\n", x16);
    printf("x24 = 0x%016llX\n", x24);
    printf("x32 = 0x%016llX\n", x32);
    printf("x40 = 0x%016llX\n", x40);
    printf("x48 = 0x%016llX\n", x48);
    printf("x56 = 0x%016llX\n", x56);
    printf("x64 = 0x%016llX\n", x64);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я вижу, проблема в том, что вы должны привести `x8` к `uint64_t` *перед* тем, как сдвигать значение.

```
x40 = x8 << 32;
```

В данном случае на 32-хбитных машинах операции над `x8` будут выполняться также, как над 32-хбитным числом (всё, что меньше `int`, приводится к `int`).

Поэтому при сдвиге на 32 бита возникнет переполнение. Чтобы этого не произошло, надо писать так:

```
x40 = (uint64_t)x8 << 32;
```

Comment: Да, вы правы :) Как раз перед вашим ответом до меня дошло :)

Answer (score 4):

Потому что вы используете формат %x, который расчитан на 32-битные числа.
Для 64-битных надо как-то так писать:

```
unsigned long long foo = 0x123456789ABCDEF0;
printf ("0x%llX\n", foo);
```

Comment: Так тоже не работает. Выводит такое: x8 = 0xBFA4E8DC000000FF, x16 = 0xBFA4E8DC0000FF00, 
x24 = 0xBFA4E8DC00FF0000, 
x32 = 0xBFA4E8DCFF000000, 
x40 = 0x0, 
x48 = 0x0, 
x56 = 0x0, 
x64 = 0x0

Comment: Вы мой код скопируйте и проверьте что он работает так, как надо. У меня вот он работает, специально проверял.

Comment: А не может быть, что проблема из за того, что я использую uint64_t, а Вы unsigned long long ? Хотя они должны быть одинаковы...

Comment: Про 32/64 не совсем верно, т.к. размер в байтах целых типов в стандарте не регламентирован. Поэтому `%x` - это для `unsigned int`, а префикс `ll` будет говорить, что это уже `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: @alexolut я не встречался с unsigned long более 32 битов, скажу честно :-)

Comment: На многих линуксах [так](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2c600ceb6a7c718). И ещё [табличка](http://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0012/) про модели данных.